# d3 graph using javascript fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web, svg

I'm trying to make a graph using d3 javascript but i get an error the the .tsv can't load resource and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at the .js file.
This is my .js code:

```
var svg;


var Statistics = {
//flag to determine if graph has already been generated
HaveGraph: new Array(),

//turn on or off relevan statistics details
ShowHideDetails: function (itemId) {
    var detailsId = '#' +itemId + 'Result'; //calc id of result div
    if ($(detailsId).css('display') == 'block') //if item is visible
        $(detailsId).hide();
    else {
        $(detailsId).show();

        //make ajax call to update the most recent statistics data
        var url = "/Statistics/ReGenerateStatisticFiles";
        $.get(url, 
            null, //here goes the params if we intend to pass params to function in format: { paramName: data } 
            function (data) {
                if(data == "OK") //if data was updated successfully --> show it
                 {
                    Statistics.DisplayGraph(itemId + 'Result');
                  }
                });

        }


},

//generate graph to show results
DisplayGraph: function (reportName) {
    if (Statistics.HaveGraph == null || Statistics.HaveGraph[reportName] == null) {
        svg = d3.select('#' + reportName).append("svg")
                   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                   .append("g")
                   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        d3.tsv(reportName + ".tsv",
            function (d) {
                d.Count = +d.Count;
                return d;
            },
            function (error, data) {
                x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.Item; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Count; })]);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)
                  .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Count"); //CHANGE!!!!!!!!!!

                svg.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(data)
                  .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.Item); })
                    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.Count); })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.Count); });

            });

        Statistics.HaveGraph[reportName] = true;
    }
}
 }


 var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
       width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10, "");
```

I can see that the .tsv file get the needed data but it doesn't show the data on the graph.
Thanks

Comment: could you share the actual stack trace?

Comment: Well, you only have one `.map` call in there, so you know where the problem has to be. Put a breakpoint on it and check the value you're getting in `data`, and work back from there.

Comment: I don't get an error that gives me stack trace the website is still runnig but when i hit f12 i can see the errors